# div sticky header not working in TailwindCSS

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a sticky header with TailwindCSS but can't seem to make it work.

I've read the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/position#sticky-positioning-elements) and seems that i only need to add `sticky top-0` to my div to make it sticky, but it doesn't work.

I've tried to clean up my code as best as I could for the sake of readability, but if you are intrested in the entire code you can find it [here.](https://github.com/carlos-dubon/radio-sulamita/blob/main/src/components/organisms/Toolbar.tsx)

```
import { Logo, ToolbarButton, IconLink, Countdown } from "@lib/atoms";
import { faWhatsapp, faFacebook } from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";
import {
  faHandHoldingHeart,
  faHeadphonesAlt,
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

export const Toolbar = () => {

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col drop-shadow-2xl">

      <div className="h-16 flex items-center justify-center bg-rs-secondary">
        <div className="container flex justify-between">
          <div className="flex gap-4 items-center">
            <IconLink
              icon={faFacebook}
              href="https://www.facebook.com/estereo.sulamita"
            />
            <IconLink icon={faWhatsapp} href="https://wa.link/logvtp" />
          </div>
          <Countdown />
        </div>
      </div>
      
      {/* I want this div to be sticky */}
      <div className="sticky top-0 h-20 flex justify-center bg-white">
        <div className="container flex items-center h-full justify-between">
          <Logo />
          <div className="flex">
            <ToolbarButton>Inicio</ToolbarButton>
            <ToolbarButton>Videos</ToolbarButton>
            <ToolbarButton>Colaboradores</ToolbarButton>
            <ToolbarButton
              className="group"
              hoverBackgroundColor="hover:bg-black"
              primary={true}
            >
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={faHandHoldingHeart}
                className="group-hover:text-white w-4"
              />
            </ToolbarButton>
            <ToolbarButton
              backgroundColor="bg-rs-primary"
              hoverBackgroundColor="hover:bg-black"
              textColor="text-white"
              primary={true}
            >
              Reproducir
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeadphonesAlt} className="w-4 ml-3" />
            </ToolbarButton>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
};
```

The above code renders the following component:

[image: header]

Also, you can find a deployed version of my app [here.](https://radio-sulamita.vercel.app)

I'd like to achieve something like [this](https://radiosulamita.org/) with my header component.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sticky` element should be direct child of the scrollable element.

In your case scrollable element is the root `__next` container. Basically it means that you need to remove this div `<div className="flex flex-col drop-shadow-2xl">` and replace it with `React.Fragment` so both of your headers, Countdown and second Header, would be direct children of this scrollable div.

Comment: Thank you, worked great! How did you knew that was the problem? It isn't stated in the docs.

Comment: Tailwind `sticky` class is just css `position: sticky`. If you know css then you already know tailwind. More info about `position` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position